# Creating VM snapshot in GCP is not snapshotting the home folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

I am trying to create a backup snapshot of my GCP instance. However, every-time I create a snapshot and boot it up, the /home/ folder contents seem to be missing from my original instance.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: please move this post to serverfault because your issue it's related with the snapshot of your instance

Comment: Do you have more than one disk attached to your instance?

Answer (score 1):

Could you give more details about the steps that you follow, to create the instance from the snapshot.

In my case I've used this commands and he have my home on the new instance:

```
gcloud compute --project=your-project-name disks snapshot disk_name_of_your_instance --zone=zone_of_your_instance --snapshot-names=name_of_your_snapshot

gcloud compute --project your-project-name disks create "your-new-instance" --size "10" --zone "us-central1-c" --source-snapshot "name_of_your_snapshot" --type "pd-standard"

gcloud beta compute --project=your-project-name instances create your-new-instance --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --subnet=your-subnet
```

Comment: tried the above steps, still same error. question: How does `gcloud beta compute` know which disk and snapshot to use? Does it use the `your-new-instance` diskname that we created in step 2?

Comment: the above finally worked. At end of the process, I had to add my SSH keys to the instance, and once I ssh'ed in, all folders were there as expected. It's still strange that SSH via browser window shows different home folder as compared to SSH via keys.